# Why merge statement inserts all the data into the target table each time it runs?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2019

I have these two table with same schema and records on different server and databases.

If the record in source table gets added or modified then it should be reflected in the target table as well but for some weird reasons it inserts all the rows in the target table each time.

I just want it to insert if new row gets added in the source or modified in the source.

Code:

```
MERGE INTO dbo.CountrySourceType AS target
USING (
                SELECT Id = Id * (- 1)
                    , Name
                    , (
                        SELECT Id
                        FROM country c
                        WHERE ISNULL(c.Name, '') = (
                                SELECT ISNULL(cs.Name, '') Name
                                FROM [192.xxx.x.xxx].WebPortal.dbo.Country cs
                                WHERE cs.Id = cst.CountryId
                                )
                            AND ISNULL(c.ContinentName, '') = (
                                SELECT ISNULL(cs.ContinentName, '') ContinentName
                                FROM [192.xxx.x.xxx].WebPortal.dbo.Country cs
                                WHERE cs.Id = cst.CountryId
                        )
                ) CountryId
                FROM [192.xxx.x.xxx].WebPortal.dbo.CountrySourceType cst
                WHERE CountryId = cst.CountryId
                ) AS source
                ON source.Id = target.Id
            WHEN NOT MATCHED BY target
                THEN
                    INSERT (
                        [Name],
                        [CountryId]
                        )
                    VALUES (
                         source.Name
                        ,source.CountryId
        
                        );
```

I tried it using the merge and narrowed down using the where clause but still it doesn't.

Comment: Seems like the merge's condition `ON source.Id = target.Id` isn't met, so it inserts new rows. Since you're not inserting any of the the source's `Id` values into the target table the target is probably using an identity column and the source and target have different values. This is made worse when you multiply the source's `Id` by `-1`.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning thanks a to. How do I get around this? like matching the Ids?

Comment: You need to provide sample data and desired results in order for us to understand what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: In `FROM [192.xxx.x.xxx].WebPortal.dbo.CountrySourceType cst WHERE CountryId = cst.CountryId` which two (or is it one) `CountryId` values do you think it is comparing? Do you just want to check that `cst.CountryId` is not `NULL`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to avoid [MERGE](https://michaeljswart.com/2021/08/what-to-avoid-if-you-want-to-use-merge/). Generally, you may have performances issues (among the other issues). You can simply add the `source` in a temporary table and just perform the update and insert by yourself.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #temp_table;

SELECT Id = Id * (- 1)
      , Name
      , (
        SELECT Id
        FROM country c
        WHERE ISNULL(c.Name, '') = (
                SELECT ISNULL(cs.Name, '') Name
                FROM [192.xxx.x.xxx].WebPortal.dbo.Country cs
                WHERE cs.Id = cst.CountryId
                )
            AND ISNULL(c.ContinentName, '') = (
                SELECT ISNULL(cs.ContinentName, '') ContinentName
                FROM [192.xxx.x.xxx].WebPortal.dbo.Country cs
                WHERE cs.Id = cst.CountryId
                )
        ) CountryId

INTO #temp_table

FROM [192.xxx.x.xxx].WebPortal.dbo.CountrySourceType cst
WHERE CountryId = cst.CountryId

UPDATE dbo.CountrySourceType 
SET name = B.name
   ,County_id = B.CountryId
FROM dbo.CountrySourceType  A
INNER JOIN #temp_table B
    ON A.[Id] = B.[Id];


INSERT INTO dbo.CountrySourceType ([Name],[CountryId])
SELECT A.name, A.CountryId
FROM #temp_table A
LEFT JOIN dbo.CountrySourceType B
    ON A.[Id] = B.[Id]
WHERE B.[Id] IS NULL;
```

---

```
INSERT INTO dbo.CountrySourceType ([Name],[CountryId])
SELECT A.name, A.CountryId
FROM #temp_table A
LEFT JOIN dbo.CountrySourceType B
    ON A.[Name] = B.[Name]
    AND A.[CountryId] = B.[CountryId]
WHERE B.[Id] IS NULL;
```

Comment: @tester sry, I have made a typo.  I have edited the initial solution, too.